# How to capture the Salesforce Lightning URL in a custom formula field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, formula-field

```
    https://example--dev.lightning.force.com/lightning/page/home?0.source=alohaHeader
```

This is the URL and I want to capture only

```
     https://example--dev.lightning.force.com/lightning
```

in a custom formula field.

Comment: URL can be changed anytime, is there a use case?

Comment: Yes, I want to append the URL to open a report in Lightning. But can this part of the URL be captured?

Answer (score 3):

You dont have to capture a URL for that, just create a formula field of type text and provide the hyperlink URL as, where first parameter is the report id. It will open the report in same tab/window

```
HYPERLINK('/00O58000002mRTN', 'Open Report ','_self')
```

Src: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5

Comment: You can avoid the awkward `_classic/` URL-translation redirect by using the native Lightning URL, like `/lightning/r/Report/MY_ID/view`.

Comment: Apparently for me, it still opens the report in lightning, without any tweaks

Comment: Huh. Interesting. I get a quick flash in the URL bar of a redirect through `/_classic/someID` before it resolves the Lightning URL. I wonder if that's context-dependent.

Comment: Probably if you have switched to lightning, it puts a cookie in your browser, so that even classic url are redirected to lighting.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal This is not helping my use-case. I have complicated requirements further Is there any way to capture that URL part in the field?

Comment: Via formula field its impossible to capture URL, formula fields only show you data on the record being querried or viewed. The solution i provided allows you to view your report, i dont see a reason why would you insists on capturing a url. You can save that URL in hierarchical custom setting and refer it in formula field. But that would be not ideal

Comment: I have a lightning component that is capturing the links to different reports, and in there I have to replace the hardcoded URL to make it dynamic for different Orgs. I can provide you more details if you require.

Comment: That bit is important, can you edit the question and provide details like you are using lightning components. Using lightning components you can capture the URL, store in database and so much more. Also if you can post the code that you have tried would also help us from reinventing the wheel and reach solution faster.

Comment: Sure. But do you have any approach for this scenario?

Comment: I can't answer without reading the full description and use case, it would be like finding a needle in a haystack.

Comment: I cannot post the code, but can I mail it to you if that works?